# unable to access aws s3 bucket from eclipse IDE

Tags: amazon-s3

I want to access s3 bucket externally from eclipse IDE. But s3 is denying permission. I have created user for s3 and gave all the access to that user

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, you have provided insufficient information for us to be able to assist you. For tips on asking questions, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) It would help if you could explain the steps you have followed (eg how you have configured Eclipse) and the exact error message. Please give us as much information as possible to assist you!

Comment: below is code i m trying

Comment: Feel free to Edit your question to add additional information. It gives more space and better formatting than a comment.

Comment: below is code i m trying